# How to resize a windows form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have two windows forms. The first one (marquee) is the default one, that runs when the solution is run, and the other one is called this way:

```
config configForm = new config();
configForm.Show();
```

I have a textbox component on configForm called txtWidthand another one called txtHeight. I also I got a button Apply. In marquee form, I got a function with this:

```
public void ApplySettings()
{
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(configForm.txtWidth.Text);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(configForm.txtHeight.Text);

    if (width > 0 && height > 0) { this.Size = new Size(width, height); }

}
```

I don't know how to call that method from configForm. If I create a new marquee form and use marqueeNew.ApplySettings() the width results 0 and an errors appears.

How do I can change the properties from the configForm to the marquee Form? I can do it in the opposite way, but that doesn't help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this method into a new `class`, along with a `get; set;` property.

something like:

```
public class MyClassName
{
    public int Height {get; set;} 
    public int Width {get; set;} 
}
```

Once you start, on the form1.load event, set these values using `MyClassName.Height = this.Height;`

then, in your second form's load event, set the value.

```
this.Height = MyClassName.Height
```

---

Otherwise, set them manually with a border set to none (and hence cannot be resized by user)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create a PUBLIC method on your marquee form with Width and Height arguments. That way, you pass those in without control references or getting extra properties in the way.

*Update - You could create a reference to your main form on the child form, by adding a public property on your child form. This way you can avoid any side effects with owner/parent relationships in both forms.

For example, in your configForm: (MarqueeForm is the type of your margquee form class)

public MarqueeForm { get; set;}

Just before your configForm.Show();, add:
configForm.MarqueeForm = this;

in your configForm, you should be able to reference the property MarqueeForm.ApplySettings(X,Y);

I don't have the full code available, so you might run into some datatyping issues, but this should point you in the right direction.

```
 public void ApplySettings(int Height, int Width)
 {
     if (Width > 0 && Height > 0) { this.Size = new Size(Width, Height); }
 }

 myForm.ApplySettings(100,200);
```

Comment: But how do I access to that method?? In marquee form I create the config form and do configForm.Show... it works. But if in configForm y create a new marquee form, I can do what you said but it's a NEW form, not the existing margin form...

Comment: why would you need to check if the form's height and width are greater than 0?

Comment: @NinjaMid76 I put public MarqueeForm { get; set;} (with the correct class name) and I get and error in that line. "Type or namespace get could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Forms
{
    public Marquee marqueeForm;
}
```

Then, when you create the new forms, you can do something like the following:

```
...
Forms.marqueeForm = new Marquee(...);
...
```

Then, from your config, you could do the following

```
Forms.marqueeForm.ApplySettings(this.txtWidth.Text, this.txtHeight.Text);
```

after clicking the apply button. Or, more directly, the clicking of "apply" on the config form could directly modify the dimensions of the marqueeForm. Just change the `ApplySettings()` method to be `ApplySettings(string widthStr, string heightStr)` or something of the sort.